# RegularExpression Validator fires every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

How to write Regex expression (with C#)  to check if there are no characters "<" and ">"?

I wrote code on console for testing:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(?!(.*<+.*)|(.*>+.*))");
string[] array = { "any text", "$baks> fgg", "att <br /> dfsdf", "<<script />> sdfsdf", "@##%%^^&&" };
foreach (var str in array)
{
    if (reg.IsMatch(str))
         Console.WriteLine("OK:\t\t{0}", str);
    else
         Console.WriteLine("XSS ATTACK:\t{0}", str);
}
```

Result is:

```
OK:             any text
XSS ATTACK:     $baks> fgg
XSS ATTACK:     att <br /> dfsdf
XSS ATTACK:     <<script />> sdfsdf
OK:             @##%%^^&&
```

But if I use this expression for validating property like

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!(.*<+.*)|(.*>+.*))")]
```

it fires on any word.
Why? How to write correct expression?

This is just simple validation on client. Full validation realized on server side with AntiXSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client-side RegularExpressionValidator uses Javascript to perform the validation. Javascript-regexes do not understand the "advanced" features, like that `(?! ... )`.

Try this as the entire expression: `[^<>]*`, meaning everything except the `<` and `>`.

Also note that the RegexValidator acts as if the expression is always 'anchored' with `^` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks! It works great.
Few minutes before I complete solution with custom client validation, but your solution is better for me.